# Search by custom taxonomy in Wordpress AJAX Search

Tags: mysql, ajax, wordpress, autocomplete

I have a custom post type witch has three custom taxonomies assigned to it: locations, type and department. On one page I habe built a search form with jQuery UI autocomplete that retrives results from a search function i have made via Ajax. The thing is that whenever i search for the category name the results aren't shown.

Ex: if i have post called ".NET Software Architect" set to location "London" the search will return results only when the searchstring is ".Net" or "Software" but not when set to "London".

```
$args = array(
    's' => $sq,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'jobs'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: That code snippet is not very helpful with the context of the question.  Can you add where `$sq` comes from and sample data within it?  Possibly the ajax call to retrieve the results as well.

Comment: $sq stands for search query so 's' => 'software'.  In the end i have splitted the search in two parts, one that searches for posts with title/content that match the search query and one that searches for taxonomies matching the values and grabs all the posts from the matched taxonomy. After that i merged the two arrays of posts and made them unique so that results won't repeat. But i am sure there has to be a way in witch you could make this two-part search into one single part, using only one query. Thanks for the hel!